# Filtering data frame by condition including data after that condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

Is there an easy way to filter my data frame so that any rows after and including a row that follows some condition are filtered out? The issue here is that I want it to be robust enough to handle a case where that condition is not met, in which the whole data frame will be returned.  Check out my examples below if that sounds confusing:

```r
library(dplyr)

## Works
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(between(row_number(), 1, which(mpg == 17.8)))

#> # A tibble: 11 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> 11  17.8     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4

## Doesn't work
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(between(row_number(), 1, which(mpg == 30.5)))

#> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo): Evaluation error: Expecting a single value: [extent=0]..
```

Created on 2018-08-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could include an `ifelse` statement to check whether the value is present in the dataframe. Also, you need to select the first row where the condition is verified to account for cases where the value is present more than once (in your example 21.0)

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
as_tibble() %>% 
filter(between(row_number(), 1,ifelse(!any(mpg == 30),n(),which(mpg == 30)[1]-1)))
## returns the whole tibble

mtcars %>% 
as_tibble() %>% 
filter(between(row_number(), 1,ifelse(!any(mpg == 21),n(),which(mpg == 21)[1]-1)))
## Returns a tibble with 0 rows

mtcars %>% 
as_tibble() %>% 
filter(between(row_number(), 1,ifelse(!any(mpg == 21.4),n(),which(mpg == 21.4)[1]-1)))
## returns:
# A tibble: 3 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4
2  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your specific example does not work because there is no mpg that equals 30.5, however, you get the same error with mpg equals 21.0 because there are two rows with that value. You will need to chose whether you want the first or the last instance of that condition

```
library(tidyverse)

#max row
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(between(row_number(), 1, which(mtcars$mpg == 21.0)[length(which(mtcars$mpg == 21.0))]))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 11
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#> 2    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
```

or

```
#min row
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(between(row_number(), 1, which(mtcars$mpg == 21.0)[1]))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 11
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
```

The example I chose just happened to be rows 1 and 2, but it illustrates the idea.

**EDIT**

The other answer by Lamia is much more elegant, and I probably thought about this too hard, but I felt like I needed to come up with something

```
library(dplyr)


filter_if_condition <- function(.data, condition, yes){
  test_cond <- enquo(condition)
  yes_filter <- enquo(yes)

  if(.data %>% filter(!!test_cond) %>% nrow() > 0){
    .data %>% filter(!!yes_filter)
  }
  else{.data}
}

mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter_if_condition(366.0 %in% mpg, between(row_number(), 1, which(mpg == 366)[1]))
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>  * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows

mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter_if_condition(18.1 %in% mpg, between(row_number(), 1, which(mpg == 18.1)[1]))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 11
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#> 2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#> 3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#> 4  21.4     6   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#> 5  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#> 6  18.1     6   225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
```

Comment: Thanks but that's why I put 30.5. Like I said in the example, I want it to be robust to handle situations where the value I'm searching for isn't there. Apologies if that wasn't clear

Comment: Ahh I see, I thought you meant with multiple hits. I'll reevaluate and update my answer. what would be the desired outcome if there is no correct condition?

Comment: return the whole data frame

Comment: Okay, I'll update. Give me a few minutes to think about it a little.